# How to cache in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, caching

I have some commonly used data that I would like to load from my database and cache during `Application_Start` in my global.asax file.  I've been reading [MSDN's article on caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/liBRary/18c1wd61(v=vs.100).aspx), but I'm a bit confused on the proper way to do this.

They example they give to insert data into cache is below:

```
Cache.Insert("CacheItem2", "Cached Item 2");
```

So I added the following to my global.asax:

```
using System.Web.Caching;
...
Cache.Insert("audioVariables", audioVariables);
```

But this throws, `An object reference is required....`.  Ok, fine - so I created an instance of the Cache class like so in `Application_start`:

```
Cache c = new Cache();
c.Insert("audioVariables", audioVariables);
```

When I call `Insert` it throws a `An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in System.Web.dll` error.

What is the proper way for me to insert an object into cache on `Application_Start`?

UPDATE:

Stack trace -

> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.]    System.Web.Caching.Cache.Insert(String key, Object value)
>   +66    MyVerbalInk.MvcApplication.Application_Start() in c:\inetpub\VerbalInk2.0\MyVerbalInk\Global.asax.cs:26
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.]
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext
>   context, HttpApplication app) +9935033
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +118
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state,
>   MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +172
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context) +336
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr
>   appContext) +296
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.]    System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext
>   context) +9913572
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
>   +101    System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +254

Comment: There is no way for `c` to come back null in the code you posted.

Comment: Sorry - you're right.  Updated.

Comment: Please show the full stack trace. Even though it's in System.Web, it may give us a clue.

Comment: That makes me wonder if `audiovariables` isn't null. Still shouldn't NRE, but... can you check the source code of Cache.Insert?

Comment: `audioVariables` definitely isn't null.  How would I check the source code for Cache.Insert - just to clarify it's a built in function for System.Web.Caching.Cache.

Comment: Which version of .NET is this? BTW, I just typed `c.Insert("", null)` and ReSharper told me that the `value` parameter is marked that it should never be null.

Comment: It's .NET Framework 4.5

Comment: See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2014/02/24/a-new-look-for-net-reference-source.aspx for info and http://referencesource.microsoft.com/ in particular, though I don't see this namespace in there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want to have a read of this article:

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/data-access/caching-data/caching-data-at-application-startup-cs

However, the gist of the problem is that in II7 or greater running in Integrated mode, there is no HttpContext available in Application_Start().  You have to use `HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert()' rather than Cache, or HttpContext.Current.Cache

Comment: Erik, out of curiosity, how would the lack of HttpContext cause the stack trace that was posted? That's very early in the Insert method, and is not inside of another method.

Comment: @JohnSaunders - I belive his stack trace is from when he instantiated a Cache object, which to be honest, no idea which Cache object he created.  From what I can see, the System.Web.Caching.Cache class is not intended to be created by itself, so who knows what might actually be happening.  I'm not motivated enough to check the sources...

Comment: @JohnSaunders in fact, the doc header for System.Web.Caching.Cache for the constructor says "This constructor is for internal use only, and was accidentally made public - do not use."